# How do I only keep the rows with the lowest and highest value in a certain column, by groups?

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

In a nutshell, how do I go from this

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), user = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2), value = c(1, 3, 5, 2, 5, 9)), .Names = c("id", "user", 
"value"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

to this?

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 3, 4, 6), user = c(1, 1, 2, 2), value = c(1, 
5, 2, 9)), .Names = c("id", "user", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Meaning, for each user, need to keep only the two rows corresponding to the lowest and highest `value`.

I'd like a solution using `dplyr`, if possible. Otherwise, any solution is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `slice` with `which.min/which.max` after grouping by 'user'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(user) %>%
   slice(c(which.min(value), which.max(value)))
#   id  user value
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1     1
#2     3     1     5
#3     4     2     2
#4     6     2     9
```

---

Or another option is `arrange` with `slice`.  After grouping by 'user', `arrange` the 'value' in ascending for each 'user' and `slice` the first and last row

```
df1 %>% 
     group_by(user) %>%
     arrange(value) %>% 
     slice(c(1, n()))
```

---

If there are ties for `min` and/or `max` 'value' and wanted to keep all the `min` and `max` rows, use `filter`

```
df1 %>%
     group_by(user) %>% 
     filter(value %in% c(min(value), max(value)))
```

Answer (score 3):

In base R, we can combine `ave` and `range` with subsetting `[` like this

```
df1[as.logical(ave(df1$value, df1$user, FUN=function(i) i %in% range(i))), ]
  id user value
1  1    1     1
3  3    1     5
4  4    2     2
6  6    2     9
```

Here, `%in%` checks if the elements of value are in `range`, a vector which returns the minimum and maximum, and `ave` applies this for each user. This returns a binary (0 , 1) vector the same length as the number of rows of the data.frame, which is converted to logical with `as.logical`. If you want something a bit shorter, `as.logical` could be changed out for `!!`.

Note that this will keep all min and max values, so depending on the type of `df$value`, this may or may not be desirable.